# Rails Radiant saving directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, content-management-system, radiant

Hallo I'm new to Rails and have one simple question.

I'm using radiant as a CMS to set up a Website. Radiant worked well for me but now I want to continue coding in NetBeans. Sounds simple enough but were are the files? I have a directory for the projekt with files for the DB and rake but no app folder? Where are the Pages? Where is that MVC Model? What ist Radiant doing with it? Do I have an generell Problem in understanding radinant's way of doing things?

Thankful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radiant stores the pages, design, and everything what you can edit in the administration console in the database. Pages, layouts,.. has their models. That's its default behavior. You can though edit the content and layout in the file system. For this I use the [file_system extension](https://github.com/nelstrom/radiant-file-system-extension) and I am quite happy with that. There might be other ones, which you could find useful, check out the [radiant extensions registry](http://ext.radiantcms.org/).